# Use sqlite database from Android app resources

Tags: database, android, sqlite, mobile, resources

I've started Android programming recently so bear with me :)

I develop an app which has all of its content stored in database.sql file.
I've implemented a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper and added database.sql to my project assets.

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
public DBHelper (Context ctx)
{
  super(ctx, "database.sql", null, 1);
}
}
```

This thing doesn't work. I just get an exception every time I try to do smth with DB :(

Comment: What's the exception being thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override onCreate and onUpdate as well, have a look to google's example [here](http://rhs.softwarerevolution.com/auto-docs/portals/google-android-mac/java/html-google-android-mac-java/NotepadCodeLab/Notepadv1Solution/src/com/android/demo/notepad1/NotesDbAdapter.java/source/SOURCE-NotesDbAdapter.java.html)

Comment: I did that. I just didn't post it here because they are just stubs in my app.

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: I get "table mytable doesn't exist"

Comment: Well that means you got an issue with your SQL queries. First check the query you wrote for creating the DB in the onCreate method. Since your using sqlite, have a look to the .sqlite file to check the state of your DB

Comment: No the problem is that an empty database is created in onCreate method instead of using my database from assets

Comment: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: This is exactly why you should copy a part from the link, cuz when the link is dead then this answer is also.

Answer (score 4):

You have 3 choices when you want to create a database locally in Android; hopefully they will support deployment directly from the APK soon.  The database needs to be in a specific location :

/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/

1. you can download the database and write it to the database folder from a known Net location.
2. you can create the database using code.
3. you can copy the database from your assets folder to the database folder (doubles space required).

Also see http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/