# Getting my app to work on my phone

Tags: database, android, android-emulator

I wrote an app android sdk version 1.5 using it's built in emulator in eclipse. I created a database outside of eclipse populated it with data and push it to the emulator folder data/data/project name/database and could access it fine from the my app, everything was working great. My final step was to test the apk file on an actual phone. When I did that the program would not work. After looking into it I found that the database file was not being uploaded into the phone. Is there a special way to install the apk file on the actual phone to get the embedded database to work? Or can I assume that since everything worked fine on the sdk 1.5 emulator that everything will work when I upload it to the market. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this question covers what you're looking for:

- [Use sqlite database from Android app resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894984/use-sqlite-database-from-android-app-resources)

Basically, you should be creating your database in code or, if you must, including it in the APK's resources or retrieving it from an outside source.